# Plot 1/sqrt(1-x^2) and arcsin together in the same graph using tikz or pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I can just plot them separately. Does someone have any idea, how to plot 1/sqrt(1-x^2) und arcsin together in the same graph using tizk or pgf?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is this the usual thingy that the arguments of trigonometric functions are in degrees, and that's why the `asin` dominates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't confirm your statement but guess that your issue is that the ordinary trigonometric functions work with degrees rather than radians.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=1/(sqrt(1-\x*\x));}]
\begin{axis}[samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymax=10, ymin=-1, xmin=0, xmax=1,
    domain=0:1,
    ] 
  \addplot [mark=none,smooth] {f(x)}; 
  \addlegendentry{$1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$}
  \addplot+ [mark=none,smooth] {asin(x)*pi/180}; 
  \addlegendentry{$\arcsin(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]